# Caching "this" when using Jquery Boilerplate paradigm?

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

I'm creating a small jquery plugin for a project. It basically, is a project management app that fetches a list of our projects from a json file, displays them and allows us to search, add and edit. It works great but i'm having a little trouble correctly using "this". Each time i use a function i have to re-cache "this" to refer to the plugins instance. My question is, is this the correct way to do that? Or, am i doing something wrong in my plugins initialization?

Below is a sample of my code. If you look in my getData and my paginate function you'll see i cache "this" in a var called context. I repeat this paradigm throughout my various functions. If i try to cache "this" during initialization and then use that cached variable throughout my function it only recognizes one instance. I have to keep re-caching it.

```
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
    var pluginName = "ezProjectList",
        defaults = {
            jsonURL:"the URL",
            status: "",
            dateText: ""
        };
    var jsonData = {};
    var string = {};
    var updateObj = {};
    var currentObject = {};
    var allData = {};
    var contexts = {
        "contextone": undefined,
        "contexttwo": undefined
    }
    var updateBoth;

    function Plugin(element, options) {
        this._element = element;
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this.options = $.extend({}, this._defaults, options);
        this.init();    
    }
    $.extend(Plugin.prototype, {
        init: function() {
            this.getData();
            $this = $(this);

        },
        getData: function() {
            var context = this;
            console.log(context);
            console.log(this);
            if (contexts[0] == undefined) {
                contexts[0] = this;
            } else {
                contexts[1] = this;
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: context.options.jsonURL,
                success: function(data) {
                    allData = data;
                    jsonData = data.projects[context.options.status];
                    context.sortProjects(jsonData);
                    context.createPages(4)
                }
            }).done(function() {
                context.paginate();
                context.setupEditForm();
                context.addProject();
                context.searchProjects();
                context.expandImages();
            });
        },
paginate: function(nav) {
            //Creates pagination from the pages
            var context = this;
            nav = $(this._element).next().attr("id");
            $("#" + nav).jPages({
                containerID: $(context._element).attr("id"),
                perPage: 1
            });
        };
$.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        var self = this;
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(self, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
                $.data(self, "plugin_" + pluginName,
                new Plugin( self, options ));
            }
        });
    };
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common problem with JavaScript. The value of `this` [depends on how the function is being called](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). When you pass a function to another function, it therefore depends how the other function is calling it.

For example, when using `$("ele").each(foo)`, `foo` is called in the context of the current element.

> [More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword this refers to the element.](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

There's a few ways to cope with it. The first way you've already identified: assign "this" to a variable and the variable will be captured by the function. You can also use [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to explicitly sets the `this` context.

e.g.

```
this.each(function () {
    if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
        $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName,
            new Plugin( this, options ));
    }
}.bind(this));
```

Finally, if you can use ES6, [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) do not bind their own `this`. So they will work without making a new var or calling Function.bind.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Are there any performance/speed issues with assigning 'this' to a variable each time you need it? My program is pretty small so i don't think it would matter too much, but just for future reference i'd like to know. I had read somewhere about using bind to maintain scope. In my case, how would i use the bind function?

Comment: One variable is probably never going to make a performance difference. Using bind would look like (moved to answer for formatting).
In this case, it's up to whichever you prefer to look at.